# la Instruction Returning Weird Memory Addresses on .asciz Symbols (gas / ld / RISCV / Devterm R-01)

Tags: assembly, ld, riscv, gnu-assembler

**EDIT:**  I've added the contents of objdump -dr to the bottom of this question.

**EDI:**  I was asked to provide the value for $gp, and the addresses of .text and .data; they are at the bottom of this question.

I'm trying to learn RISC-V assembly using gas and ld.  I'm running my code natively on a Devterm R-1.  My issue is that the la pseudoinstruction does not seem to always give me a usable memory address when I use .asciz.  Here is what I have:

**Filename m.asm**

```
     .global start

     .text
_start:
     la     a1,     w1
     la     a2,     w2
     la     a3,     w3
     la     a4,     w4
     la     a5,     w5

     nop

     addi     a0,     x0,     0
     addi     a7,     x0,     93
     ecall

     .data
w1:  .asciz "Odd"
w2:  .asciz "Even"
w3:  .asciz "NineChars"
w4:  .asciz "\n"
w5:  .asciz "I"
```

I built an executable with these commands:

```
as m.asm -g -o m.o
ld m.o -o m
```

And tested with:

```
gdb m
```

I stepped down to the `nop` instruction and used p to print the memory addresses stored at each register:

```
a1 = 69912
a2 = 69916
a3 = 69921
a4 = 183252031331
a5 = 183252031333
```

The first three look reasonable and do indeed contain data if I use `x/c` to view the contents as characters.  However, trying to do the same to `a4` or `a5` gives me a `cannot access memory at address...` error.

**System details:**
OS is:
"Linux devterm-R01 5.4.61 #12 PREEMPT Wed Mar 30 14:44:22 CST 2022 riscv64 riscv64 riscv64 GNU/Linux"

gas is version is 2.39
ld is version 2.39
gdb is version 12.1

**Contents of objdump -dr m:**
'''
m:  file format elf64-littleriscv

```
 auipc     a1,     0x1
 addi      a1,     a1,     48     # 11118 <__DATA_BEGIN__>
 auipc     a2,     0x1
 addi      a2,     a2,     44     # 1111c <w2>
 auipc     a3,     0x1
 addi      a3,     a3,     41     # 11121 <w3>
 addi      a4,     gp,     -2029  # 1112bj <w4>
 addi      a5,     gp,     -2027  # 1112d  <w5>
 nop
 li        a0,     0
 li        a7,     93
 ecall
```

'''

Edit:  I was asked to provide the value of gp and the start addresses for code and data:
in gdb, `r $gp = 0x2aaaac1f50`

in objdump -t,

```
00000000000100e8 = .text
0000000000011118 = .data
```

**Ask:**
Can someone educate me into what is happening with the memory addresses returned by la on these .asciz strings?  As they are they are unusable.

Comment: Show the disassembly for the code so we can see the `la` pseudo instruction expansions.

Comment: Interesting. Can you also share the value in `gp`?  And code section addr and data section addr?

Comment: @ErikEidt, I have added the value of gp, as well as the addresses of .text and .data.

Comment: I don't know why the code to access w1 differs from the code to access w4.  However, as a standalone executable it seems that `gp` is not being initialized.  Suggest to add `la gp, w1+2048` or something equivalent as first line.

Comment: @ErikEidt, I tried putting ```la gp, w1+2048``` just after my _start.  I looked at it in ```objdump -dr``` and this was translated to ```mv gp, gp```.  I then went into gdb and tried to read the contents of a1 through a5.  As usual, a4 and a5 were not accessible.

Comment: Maybe try `la gp, w1` then `addi gp, 1024` twice.

Comment: @ErikEidt  This did work, and I was able to read the contents of registers a1 through a5.  If you write this as a solution I'll happily mark it correct/upvoted so you can get credit for helping me.

Am I supposed to be setting gp at the start of a program?  None of the tutorial listings I've been following hinted at this.  Or is this solution a workaround for a bug somewhere in the toolchain?

Comment: As bare metal you have to set `gp`, if used by. However, I don't know why your environment uses the different approaches to access globals, especially when they are so near to each other.